# nerdctl run command in scripts to run in background

Tags: nerdctl

When i execute the nerdctl command on terminal with (&) to run in the background , i could get back to the prompt with an "enter" but the same is not working when i put the nerdctl command in scripts. Is there a way to solve this ?

```
nerdctl run --rm --name Test --env "KEY_FILE=key.pem" --env "CERT_FILE=cert.pem" --env "CA_FILE=ca.pem" --env "CONFIG_FILE=config.json" --env "GNMI_PORT=10164" -p "10164:10164" -v "/root/cfg:/conf" go-sim:21.11.2 &
```

Thanks in advance.